# Animation does not Scrub

Tags: animation

I'm using mp4 video projected onto a 2d plane in the 3d viewer, but cant get them to animate or scrub through timeline in texture or material mode unless I open up an extra window with cycles render on. Is there a way to simply allow it to animate without having to open up an extra render preview window?

PS: Thanks for the support on my last questions. you Blender Gurus are the best!

Answer (score 0):

If you use video as reference, best way to do this - using image empty.

Image empty always shows current frame; over methods, that i'm tried gives +-1 frame offset. To add image empty press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> *Empty* -> *Image*

Comment: Allow me to clarify: The clip (actually a mov, not mp4) with alpha is embedded into a plane object and is to be used "not as a reference", but as an actual "active element" inside the scene, that interacts with 3D elements inside. my problem is, that the animation frames in the video clip do not refresh when the time line is scrubbed/advanced until I set the scene to render. does not work in either texture, or material mode unless I open up an additional viewport window and view it as render. upon which, all windows will refresh.

Comment: I don't know methods, that solves this problem, use yours. And vote my feature request: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Z0bbbc/

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Simply go to **Add**, on the bottom on 3d panel, then **Mesh > Image as Plane** and check box **Animate Image Sequence** on the **Operator Presets** to the left. It will then animate in Material Mode.